# テンプレートのインライン展開時におけるシンボル解決

Tags: c++, c++11

次のようなコードを考えます。
1. inline指定されたテンプレート関数func
2. funcを通してクラスBのメンバにアクセスするクラスA
3. クラスBの実装はクラスAより後にある

```
template<class T>
inline func()
{
    cout << T::GetClassName() << endl;
}

class B;
class A {
    void Run(){
        func<B>();
        //::B::GetClassName(); error
    }
};

class B {
public:
    static string GetClassName(){
        return "B";
    }
};
```

この場合、
インライン展開されたテンプレート関数は、シンボルGetClassNameを解決するため、クラスBの完全な型情報が必要だと思うのですが、C++11の規格ではどうなってるでしょうか？

ちなみにgcc4.8で試したところ、上記のコードはコンパイルが通りましたが、コメントアウト箇所を有効にしたところ、完全な型情報を求められコンパイルエラーになりました。

Comment: 英語版SOの [Can the point-of-instantiation be delayed until the end of the translation unit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030403/) が参考になるかと思います。

Answer (score 4):

**[2016-02-18 01:57注記: 以下の内容は規格書の読み間違いの可能性が高いです。コメントも参照して下さい]**

`A::Run` 中で、 `func<B>()` が問題なく呼び出せることはC++規格の範囲内であると思います。

まず、ISO/IEC 14882:2011 14.6.4.1 Point of instantiation 第6段落にはこうあります。

> The instantiation context of an expression that depends on the template arguments is the set of declarations with external linkage declared prior to the point of instantiation of the template specialization in the same translation unit.

この段落では、テンプレート引数に依存する式 (今回の質問では `cout << T::GetClassName() << endl;`) のインスタンス化の際、インスタンス化された地点 (*the point of instantiation* -- 今回の質問では `func<B>()` を呼び出した箇所) 以前に宣言されたものが使えます (かなり端折り＆意訳しているので、正確なところは引用した原文をどうぞ)。

これだけでは、`func<B>()` が呼び出された箇所の前には `B::GetClassName` の宣言がないため、むしろ不適合に読めますが、続く第7段落にはこう書かれています。

> A specialization for a function template, a member function template, or of a member function or static data member of a class template may have multiple points of instantiations within a translation unit, and in addition to the points of instantiation described above, for any such specialization that has a point of instantiation within the translation unit, **the end of the translation unit is also considered a point of instantiation**.

キモとなる部分を強調しましたが、こちらもざっくり説明すると、関数テンプレートなどの特殊化 (`specialization`) においては、翻訳単位の終端部分をインスタンス化された地点とみなすとあります。第6段落と合わせると、翻訳単位全体の宣言がインスタンス化する際に使えることになります。
そのため、テキストの位置的には、`func<B>()` の呼び出しが `B::GetClassName` の宣言の前にありますが、特殊化の際には、 `B::GetClassName` が含まれます。

Comment: 迅速な回答誠に有り難うございます。直接仕様にはまだ目を通していないので恐縮ですが、引用いただいた英文の解釈に相違が有ったのでコメントさせていただきます。

第7段落の記述、
"the end of the translation unit is 'also' considered a point of instantiation."
は複数あるpoint of instantiationのうち1つに終端を含めることが出来るという補足的な記述に読めます。

これと第6段の記述を合わせると、各point of instantiationに対して、各々がより手前の位置に宣言を要求しているという解釈をしました。

この解釈では質問の事例においてpoint of instantiationはA::Run()内とファイル終端の2箇所になると考えられます。

ファイル終端に関しては前方にB:: GetClassName()の実装があるため良いとして、問題のA::Run()内の実装ですが、この位置から見て前方にB:: GetClassName()の実装が存在しないためこの記述は認められないように思います。

お手数ですが解釈に誤りあればご指摘いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 私も最初はその解釈をしていました。しかし、その解釈では、テンプレート引数が同一でも、 *point of instantiation* が異なることで、それぞれの解釈の内容が異なってしまうことになります。今回は解釈が異なると仮定すると片方がコンパイルエラーになるのですが、そうではなく、オーバーロードの違いなどでコンパイルが通るにもかかわらず挙動が異なる2種類のものができてしまうパターンも作れてしまいます。とすると、同じ特殊化にもかかわらず、内容が異なる実体ができてしまい、そういった場合は未定義となるため、この解釈ではテンプレート関数自体が使い物にならなくなります。規格の他の部分でも、そのギャップを埋める既定を見付けられなかったため、「複数の *point of instantiation* を取り得るけれど、それらの特殊化においては、翻訳単位の末尾が *pont of instantiation* とみなすものとする」という解釈ができそうだと思い、それを下敷に回答を行いました。ただ、読み返すと、どうにもこの解釈には無理がありそうですね。ぽっと出で末尾に追加された *point of instantiation* に何か意味があるはずだとは思うのですが。

Comment: どの時点の規格書を参照されているのかわからないので参照できないのですが、N3242=11-0012ではその辺りの記載が少し変わっているようです。
"the end of ..."の記載がなく、代わりに"If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings according to the one definition rule (3.2), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required."とあります。point of instantiationに依存して挙動が異なるコードは不正のようです。

Comment: 根拠としている該当文面は [CWG 993](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue993) で追加されたようです（C++11以降で有効）。どうも @KazukiTsunemi さんが参照されたN3242は、このCWG#993が反映される前のDraftのようですね。最後のill-formedとなる条件ですが、あくまで異なるPOIでの特殊化によりODR違反を引き起こす場合とありますから、今回のケースでは不正とは言えない気がしました...